# Facebook Comment box Installed OK but moderator view tab not showing

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have installed the Facebook comment box social plugin and it works okay, people leave comments, comments show, all good. But the Moderator view tab does not show.

- admins and app-id meta tags OK.
- Debugger does not report any problems on the page.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.manuelasmanual.com%2Finfo.htm

**URL Not Safe for Work**

There are many other similar questions here on stackoverflow but none answered.

Has anyone got an obvious idea of why this could happen?

Comment: Please give a notice when content not safe for work will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try scraping the page as the administrator / developer of the application. Also, make sure the link that the Comment Box connects to is also scraped (and has the `fb:admins` parameter set). This should update the information on the page and show the moderator view for your comment box.

Comment: My mistake I mixed it up with page id

Comment: Scraping also solved this for me. Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I declared this in body tag:

> ```
> <script>
>   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>     FB.init({
>       appId      : '1393766870937xxx',
>       xfbml      : true,
>       version    : 'v2.2'
>     });
>   };
>
>   (function(d, s, id){
>      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
>      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
>      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
>    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
> </script>
> ```

And we must have this in head tag:

> ```
> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1393766870937xxx">
> ```

So i think It seems redundant to declare in two places.